# Label and TextBox: same font looks different

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, fonts

I have `Label` and `TextBox` in Windows Forms, C#, .NET.

I can see a strange behaviour: I set the same Font to `Label` and `TextBox`, and the same word looks different there:

[image: Word "_DATEU" looks almost like bold in label]

The Font is Tahoma, 10.25pt.
As you can see, on the top is a `Label`, and it looks like if it had Bold style comparing to `TextBox`.
Why does this happen? Can I make my `TextBox` and Label look the same with this font?

Comment: either this, or setting the **TextBox** to bold, would probably be as close as you're going to get.

Comment: Its possible that the floating precision has caused the textbox one to scale down a size whilst the label has scaled up.. does this same effect happen when using integer values?

Comment: With integer font size `Label` and `TextBox` look the same. Any ideas, how to make `TextBox` eat 10.25pt font size?

Comment: I wish I could switch to WPF :) . If there's nothing to do but to choose 10pt, thank you

Comment: No worries, I've moved my last comment into an answer since it may be easier for future users to discover the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by floating precision, it would appear that labels choose to round up whilst textboxes round down to the nearest whole number (integer).

Its possible that WPF can get around this since it uses DirectX to handle its drawing. Since winforms uses GDI there isn't a lot of support for floating precision within drawing.

You may be better off just using `10pt` since there isn't a lot of different between this and `10.25`... You are using it anyway for your textbox right? :)

Comment: That's a possible solution. See my comment above. Of course, it would be better to use 10.25pt, as all my UI uses this font, but switching to 10pt may be the only way, it seems.

Comment: @ArtemKachanovskyi - You may have set it as so but for the most part this answer would apply to all your controls, they will each be deciding which way to round to the nearest integer.